# verify placeholder text by using protractor for an angular js app

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a text field having an placeholder value.
I want to check what text it is holding.
Please help me regarding this issue.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row form-group"> 
 <div input-container placeholder="Zip Code" error="yourInfoForm.zipcode. $error"> 
   <input fr-validate type="text" regex-value="regex.usZipCodes" name="fname" class="form-control border-radius-0" ng-maxlength="15" ng-model="yourInfo.zipcode" /> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `element.getAttribute('value')`.

You can get more info here:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#the-result-of-gettext-from-an-input-element-is-always-empty

Comment: what value holds here?

Comment: That's it - you have to find element, and then use .getAttribute('value') - it will return the placeholder

Comment: <div class="row form-group">
                            <div input-container 

placeholder="Zip Code" error="yourInfoForm.zipcode.

$error">
                                <input fr-validate 

type="text" regex-value="regex.usZipCodes" name="fname" 

class="form-control border-radius-0" ng-maxlength="15" 

ng-model="yourInfo.zipcode" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

Comment: this is my code..can u help me to write code for that..i am new to protractor,am not able to find it.

Comment: just add an ID tag to whatever you want to test, and go : by.id('myid').getAttribute('value')

Comment: You can add ID tag to the div with input container: id="myid"

Comment: expect(element(by.css('[name="ffname"]')).getAttribute('value')).toEqual('First name');this is failing..is this correct?

Comment: i have added name attribute instead of id

Comment: error message is " Expected null to equal 'First name'."

Comment: It will be easier to add an ID to the input, instead of attribute name - I belive you cannot find element by that way.

Comment: Try adding ID to the input, and go: expect(by.id('myid').getAttribute('value').toEqual('First name')

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark this as an answer.

Comment: FYI: `.getAttribute('value')` will return nothing (blank) if there is nothing in the input. You must use `.getAttribute('placeholder')`.  This brings up a question for me, is there a way to validate the appearance of that placeholder on the page without manually testing or doing screenshot comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

expect(element(by.css('[name="ffname"]')).getAttribute('value').getText()).toEqual('First name');